# Neo4j bad performance with OR operator

Tags: neo4j, cypher, graph-databases, query-performance, boolean-expression

I am using neo4j-3.5 community version .And have built a huge graph using neo4j containing ~20 million nodes on movie data. I have also inserted genres & keywords and constructed the graph.
The following query takes > 5 seconds

```
MATCH 
    (p:`Program`),  
    (p:Program)-[genre:of_genre]->(g:Genre), 
    (p:Program)-[key_rel:associated_keyword]->(k:Keyword)
  WHERE   
    ((g.id IN [1010]) OR (k.id IN ['keyword_121'])) AND 
    ((p.show_type IN ['movie'])) AND 
    (p.imdb_score > 0)
  RETURN distinct p.id, p.imdb_score
  ORDER BY p.imdb_score desc
  LIMIT 50
```

whereas if i replace OR with AND, it takes < 100 ms.

```
MATCH 
    (p:`Program`),  
    (p:Program)-[genre:of_genre]->(g:Genre), 
    (p:Program)-[key_rel:associated_keyword]->(k:Keyword)
  WHERE   
    ((g.id IN [1010]) AND (k.id IN ['keyword_121'])) AND 
    ((p.show_type IN ['movie'])) AND 
    (p.imdb_score > 0)
  RETURN distinct p.id, p.imdb_score
  ORDER BY p.imdb_score desc
  LIMIT 50
```

Indexes are there on genre id and keyword id.

> The PROFILE response for 'OR' :

[image]

> THE PROFILE response for 'AND' :

[image]

Any better way to write the query with OR operator?

Comment: Can you run your query with `PROFILE` in the start and share the expanded plan here?

Comment: @Raj: I have updated the question with PROFILE output.

Comment: It's hard to tell what part of the plan corresponds with which parts of the query. Please expand all elements of the plan first (the double-down arrow in the lower right corner of the result pane for the query, when viewing the query plan) then add that to your question, replacing the collapsed plan you provided.

Comment: @InverseFalcon: I have updated the plan for the queries.

Answer (score 0):

**Your query builds a cartesian product between 3 disconnected patterns.**

Try the following query:

```
  MATCH 
    (k:Keyword)<-[key_rel:associated_keyword]-(p:Program)-[genre:of_genre]->(g:Genre)
  WHERE   
    ((g.id IN [1010]) OR (k.id IN ['keyword_121'])) AND 
    ((p.show_type IN ['movie'])) AND (p.imdb_score > 0)
  RETURN distinct p.id, p.imdb_score
  ORDER BY p.imdb_score desc
  LIMIT 50
```

Comment: This still takes similar time as before.

Comment: @Raj i think there is no need on `IN`  we can use equals operator

Comment: Used IN in case it's required to match against more than one ids.

Comment: @sravan Can you check once without IN?

Comment: @Govind Singh: I have to use IN  operator.

Answer (score 0):

This *may* work better for you:

```
OPTIONAL MATCH (g:Genre) WHERE g.id IN [1010]
OPTIONAL MATCH (k:Keyword) WHERE k.id IN ['keyword_121']
WITH g, k
MATCH (p:`Program`)
WHERE
  p.show_type IN ['movie'] AND
  p.imdb_score > 0 AND
  ((p)-[:of_genre]->(g) OR (p)-[:associated_keyword]->(k))
RETURN distinct p.id, p.imdb_score
ORDER BY p.imdb_score desc
LIMIT 50
```

This query might use both of your indexes (or at least you may be able to give [hints](https://neo4j.com/docs/developer-manual/3.4/cypher/query-tuning/using/#query-using-index-hint) to use them). Also, you may want to create an index on `:Program(show_type)` if movies are not very common in your DB.

The `WHERE` clause also just tests for the existence of a single desired `:of_genre` or `:associated_keyword` relationship -- it does not try to actually scan for and hold in memory all of them.

Comment: This change doesn't improve the performance to the expected one. ~4 seconds become ~1.5 seconds. But the 'AND' query executes within 100ms.

Comment: You shouldn't expect performance to improve to that level. Understand that simply changing OR to AND isn't simple. It changes the logic of what the query has to do to be correct. It can't rely only on traversing from `k`, it has to do the work of traversing from `g` that otherwise wouldn't be needed if using AND. More work has to be done because there's no other choice for it to be logically correct.

Comment: You should PROFILE cybersam's query. If it uses an index lookup on `k` and `g` then it may be the best you can get.